# View variable data while debugging in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, debugging

I come from a .Net world so I'm used to just hovering over a variable while debugging and seeing what its value is.
In Objective-C I am incredibly confused on how to do that.
If I hover over it, I get a small popup with lots of information...that doesn't help me at all.
For example, I have an object called "myServer" and it is an instance of a "Server" that I have created through CoreData.  One of its properties is "root" which is a simple NSString.
I cannot for the LIFE of me figure out how to view what the value of `[myServer root]` is.
Can some please give me some advice on this?

Comment: Hovering over values in XCode, and navigating the disclosure triangles in those popups, works so well that I move mountains to develop linux-targeted programs in OS X to enjoy that behaviour.

Comment: When I hover over it I get a popup that says it's of type "Server" and when you expand that triangle it says it is of type "ManagedObject" and from there it's just a bunch of useless information that at no point shows the properties I have defined.

Comment: Also, here is what I see when I hover over an NSString called "username".  http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/screengrabs/9491a92593d4c0be7df4215c30400c2d.PNG

There is NO data in there that makes any sense to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the gdb console, type

```
po [myServer root]
```

Comment: Thank you for that, that answers this question and helped me realize that I need help debugging CoreData objects.  Thanks!

Comment: Stupid question I'm sure, but how do I get this GDB console to show up in Xcode? I'm in version 5.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use GDB from the command line.  Open a terminal and type

```
gdb
attach <your process name>
```

(be sure your program was built with debugging symbols).  Then, when your variable name is in scope (e.g. when you break somewhere relevant) type

```
po variableName
```

to view its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way to deal with this is to log directly from a breakpoint.

To do this, create a breakpoint after the value you want to see has been set, then edit it. Add a breakpoint action of 'log', and put the expression you want logged within a pair of @ symbols. Check the box to the right, ensuring that the breakpoint doesn't actually cause a stop. The value will be output to the debugger console on doing a run & debug.

Doing it this way you (a) don't clutter your source, (b) can dis/enable the breakpoint at will according to your immediate needs, and (c) don't need to stop execution.

This and other very handy xcode tips can be culled from [Joar Wingfors' 'Debugging with Xcode' talk.](http://theocacao.com/document.page/570)